# ForeignKey to 'self' in sub-application throws error on makemigrations in Django project

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-1.10

I'm currently working on an large Django project (version 1.10.7) and am running into an error with a model field in a sub-application. Here's what the basic structure looks like:

```
project/
    app_one/
        __init__.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        app_two/
            __init__.py
            apps.py
            models.py
            urls.py
            views.py
```

The model and field in question looks like this (`project/app_one/app_two/models.py`):

```
class SampleModel(model.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='members')
```

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations app_one.app_two` in the root folder I get this error message:

> File .../django/db/models/utils.py", line 23, in make_model_tuple
>       "must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'." % model ValueError: Invalid model reference 'app_one.app_two.SampleModel'. String model
>   references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.

Here is code from other files that are relevant:

**project/settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = filter(None, (
    ...
    'app_one',
    'app_one.app_two',
    ...
)
```

**project/app_one/app_two/apps.py**:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppOneAppTwoConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_one.app_two'
    label = 'app_one.app_two'
```

**project/app_one/app_two/__init__.py**:

```
default_app_config = 'app_one.app_two.apps.AppOneAppTwoConfig'
```

I believe the error here is that Django is only looking for one `.` in the full model name (`app_one.app_two.SampleModel`) to separate the app label from the model name in `django/db/models/utils.py`, and since there are two in this case, it fails.

**My question is**: This seems like a weird for Django not to account for...is there anyway to retain the dot notation of the app label and still have a self-referencing ForeignKey in a sub-application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention, [it seems to be a lookup error](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.7/django/db/models/utils.py#L21) when the project is trying to locate your app due to the nested apps. This can be solved by specifying the app name with an [app_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#app-label) in the models internal meta class:

```py
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app_two'
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I tried the methods you described and that doesn't work either - same error. It seems when it parsed the related fields, it winds up referencing the app_label no matter what, and the double dots cause the same error. I was able to solve it though, and I'll create an answer to my question that highlights my solution.

Comment: Ah, have you tried adding `app_label = 'app_two'` in the Meta class of the model?

Comment: @ColtyHarrison Cheers, I have updated my answer in case you want to mark it as a solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing the `app_label` to `'app_one_app_two'` in `apps.py`. Because django references this when registering the related models, it doesn't break. All migrations are then registered under that label as well.